# next("some class") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div class="linksrtitle">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="linksrspace"></div>
<div class="linksrwrap">  // this div should be slided
<a class="linkr" href="volim-da-stoje.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="linkr" href="ova-salate-je-umrla.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
<a class="linkr" href="nova-rasa.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
<div class="linksrspace"></div>
```

JS

```
$(".linksrtitle").click(function(){
   $(this).next(".linksrwrap").slideToggle();  // doesn't work
});
```

Why this click event doesn't work. Console is empty.

Comment: Try reading the docs: https://api.jquery.com/next/ Get the **immediately following** sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the **next sibling only if it matches that selector.**   `$(".linksrtitle").next()` is always `.linksrspace` no matter what `$(".linksrtitle").next(".linksrwrap")` is still `.linksrspace` but returns null as it's not `.linksrwrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)**(with **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)**, if multiple sibling with same class are there) to get that. **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** only select immediate following sibling.

```js
$(".linksrtitle").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".linksrwrap").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="linksrtitle">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="linksrspace"></div>
<div class="linksrwrap">// this div should be slided
  <a class="linkr" href="volim-da-stoje.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a class="linkr" href="ova-salate-je-umrla.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
  <a class="linkr" href="nova-rasa.php">Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
<div class="linksrspace"></div>
```

Comment: next should be next, shouldn't it. anyway, solved, thanks a lot.

Comment: next *is* next, but linksrwrap is *not* the next when after linksrtitle, linksrspace is

Comment: @freedomn-m, `linksrwrap` IS next of class `linksrwrap`. I wrote `next(".linksrwrap")` and not just `next()`

Comment: @bonaca : which selects the immediate following element only if, which have class `linksrwrap` ............ go through the docs you will get it ;)

Comment: @bonaca Given the sequence "1","2","3", which is the next one after "1" - it's "2".  It's always "2".  If you then say, *give me the next one if it's "3"*, it's not "3", it's still "2" which is not "3".   It's **not** *give me the next one **that is** "3"*, it's *give me the next one **if** it is 3*".

Comment: I'll concur that there's the possibility of confusion, but that's what `.nextAll('filter')` is for